# Modifying Reveal.js Defaults in IPython Notebook Slide Generation

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js

I started experimenting today with the auto-generation of slides from markup in an IPython notebook. This is a new feature in IPython 1.0. I'd like to change the default transition that is used by Reveal.js in the slide presentation. It appears one can control the defaults with a bit of Javascript of the form

```
<script>
Reveal.initialize({
  transition: 'concave'
});
</script>
```

I'm wondering where to put this code for it to modify the slide generation process when making a call to 'ipython nbconvert' from the command line. Can I embed this in the notebook itself somehow and have it take effect?